# Why is this error Method sheets of Object '_workbook' failed occuring in my macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I started learning VBA for excel 2007. Can anyone help why this error is happening while execution:

The code is

```
Public Sub LastVariable_Check()
    'Check if Last Variable is of latest month sales

    'lastvariable  = lv

    lv = wkbOut.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1",Range("B1").End(xlToRight)).End(xlToRight).Text
    If "0" & Mid(lv, InStr(lv, "Month/") + 6, 1) = strmth _
    And Mid(lv, InStr(lv, "Month/") + 8, 4) = strYear Then
        Set wkbRaw = Workbooks.Open(strInputQCPath & "Errorlog.xlsx")

        wkbRaw.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Value = "Correct"
        wkbRaw.SaveAs Filename:=strInputQCPath & "Errorlog.xlsx"
        wkbRaw.Close
    Else
        Set wkbRaw = Workbooks.Open(strInputQCPath & "Errorlog.xlsx")

        wkbRaw.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Value = "Incorrect"
        wkbRaw.SaveAs Filename:=strInputQCPath & "Errorlog.xlsx"
        wkbRaw.Close
    End If 
End Sub
```

Please help
Thanks!

Comment: On what line does the error occur? Does the workbook have Sheet1?

Comment: Hi,The problem got solved. Can I delete the question? Actually I had called this LastVariable_Check, outside the scope of this workbook wkbOut. Just cut-pasted and called the it before the code where I was saving wkbOut as different worksheet name and it worked.

Comment: @AmitBarnwal if you feel it could help others you can answer your own question & accept it.

Comment: missing declared variables can make all the difference, this is why `Option Explicit` should be default - Thanks to Microsoft for allowing spelling errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had called this LastVariable_Check, outside the scope of this workbook wkbOut. Just cut-pasted and called the it before the code where I was saving wkbOut as different worksheet name and it worked.